# Tensorflow, how much faster is GPU vs CPU? (cosine similarity computation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

Yesterday I tried GPU for computation and I was very disappointed. My idea was that GPU (with thousands of cores) will be at least 1k faster than CPU.

I wanted first to use GPU for the computation of Cosine similarity, and let me tell you the results.

- First Off, GPU is not capable to compute the pairwise similarity (Matrix to Matrix) it says out of memory regardless of the fact that the memory of GPU was 24 GB RAM (it was model - 2x RTX 3090, 88.8 tflops 24 GB ram card, 64 GB ram system)

So I had to use vector to matrix computation, where you then need do the iteration eg if your original matrix has 400k rows so it means you have to do 400k time the iteration vector to matrix computation of Cosine similarity.

I used btw Tensor flow for this like that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
Xn = np.random.uniform(0,10, (400000,100)).astype('float32')
X = tf.constant(Xn)

count = 1000 * 100
for i in range(count):
    tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(
        X[0],
        X,
        axis=-1
    )
```

As you can see the Matrix is shape of 400k, 100 means 400k rows 100 columns.

Then I made the iterations above it is 100k. **These 100k took 176 seconds**, which is yes like 20x faster than CPU on my notebook, but to be honest same results you can achieve with python Numba library which translates python code to machine native code. (but then 400k iterations takes 30 mins though - with Numba, don't know how long with GPU)

Result is, I am dissapointed, I expected to be GPU more powerful in terms of memory, and mainly at least 1000 x faster than CPU.. I expected the times to be in manner of mili or micro seconds..

**Why they still say this card has power of 80 teraflops etc when then you compute it same time as on CPU with native instructions. And mainly - CPU has only few cores, GPU has thousand of cores..**

Can I make it somehow faster?

Comment: It all comes down that GPUs are best for parallel processing, and your code is completely sequential. You cannot do parallel computing without knowing anything about parallel computing, and this applies very strongly to GPUs.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy good point. you think that TF doesn't paralelize auotmatically the code over multiple GPU and mainly over multiple GPU cores / threads?